# imap_open recursively tried for password and fails

Tags: imap, imap-open

I m trying to use imap_open to open a remote mail box. When the password is incorrect it tries a number of time and gives warning and fails.

Where as php list if imap_open is not successfully it will return false.

This is not happening.

Please help

PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying CRAM-MD5 authentication after incorrect password or account name (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying CRAM-MD5 authentication after incorrect password or account name (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Kerberos error: No credentials cache found (try running kinit) for mail.server.com (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after incorrect password or account name (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after incorrect password or account name (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: too many failed logins (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

The only solution appears to me is to disable the notice of suppress such notice with @ in php

Answer (score -1):

my workaround:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```